# How to test if browser support paste event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, paste

I have following code to test if browser support paste event, it return true on Firefox but paste event is not fired.

```
var is_paste_supported = (function() {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.setAttribute('onpaste', 'return;');
    return typeof el.onpaste == "function";
})();
```

Is there better test for paste event except browser sniff?

Comment: Modernizr's `hasEvent()`, maybe?

Comment: @RickHitchcock It seems that it only fire if focused in input elements.

Comment: check this: http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

Comment: how are you listening for the paste event?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody the issue is resolved, the paste event is fired only when you focus in input element. The code is working as expected, firefox do support paste event.